# When I add a new .c file, Android Studio informs me that it is not part of the project

Tags: android, c++, c, android-studio, java-native-interface

I'm developing an Android Studio project with JNI code, and I added a .c and .h source file manually to the project. However, Android Studio informs me that the file is not part of the project. I Googled a bit and the solution seems to be to include it in Android.mk, but I did a search for that file and there are multiple such files on my Windows system, so I'm not sure which to change.

Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to add the .c file (full path) to my CMakeLists.txt as a separate line under add_library, and then it worked.